# Paragraph hanging based on lines

Tags: paragraphs

Paragraph hanging is the indentation for a paragraph upon a new paragraph starts, many novels employ this style.

[image: Example hanging]

I am currently creating this using:

```latex
\chapter{Chapter}
The first line is never indented. The line continues on a new line, without an indent.

As you can see the second paragraph has an indent, so would have the following lines, but does not break into any whitespace.

\section*{}
Sometimes you do want to have whitespace. There won't be any indent again.

My question is: Is it possible to do this without extra new lines or par on the end of the line? And creating the whitespace just by the empty newline?
```

I would, instead want to use the syntax below.

```latex
\chapter{Chapter}
The first line is never indented. The line continues on a new line, without an indent.
As you can see the second paragraph has an indent, so would have the following lines, but does not break into any whitespace.

Sometimes you do want to have whitespace. There won't be any indent again.
My question is: Is it possible to do this without extra new lines or par on the end of the line? And creating the whitespace just by the empty newline?
```

Can I create a line based "paragraphs" and still get them hanging?

Comment: All in all you're asking to save a few keystrokes for the manual formatting of this, in exchange for a not well-tested and possibly fragile syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I do not recommend actually using this, this isn't thoroughly tested and could have horrible side effects.

Instead of putting the macro `\strangeparsyntax` in `\AtBeginDocument`, you could as well use it in a local group (using `\begingroup\strangeparsyntax <your text>\endgroup`).

This answer works by making the endlinechar an active character and defining it to introduce the requested space. This way a single new line will start a new paragraph with the usual indent. Every additional new line will introduce additional vertical space (meaning two additional new lines will double the space, and using an additional new line after a heading will also increase the space).

```
\documentclass[]{book}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\strangeparsyntax
  {%
    \catcode`\^^M\active
    \begingroup\lccode`~=`\^^M
    \lowercase
      {\endgroup
        \def~%
          {%
            \par
            \@ifnextchar~%
              {\bigskip\@afterindentfalse\@afterheading}%
              {}%
          }%
      }%
  }
\makeatother
\AtBeginDocument{\strangeparsyntax}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}
The first line is never indented. The line continues on a new line, without an indent.
As you can see the second paragraph has an indent, so would have the following lines, but does not break into any whitespace.

Sometimes you do want to have whitespace. There won't be any indent again.
My question is: Is it possible to do this without extra new lines or par on the end of the line? And creating the whitespace just by the empty newline?


This paragraph will not be indented and the space before it will be doubled compared to the paragraph before this one.

\section{Section}
Leaving no space in between a sectioning command and the following text will give the normal spacing.

\section{Section}

With an additional new line between a heading and the text there will also be additional space.
\end{document}
```

[image]

With a small modification (ignoring newlines when not used in horizontal mode) we could also sort of fix the space doubling.

```
\documentclass[]{book}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\strangeparsyntax
  {%
    \catcode`\^^M\active
    \begingroup\lccode`~=`\^^M
    \lowercase
      {\endgroup
        \def~%
          {%
            \ifhmode\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
            \@gobble
              {%
                \par
                \@ifnextchar~%
                  {\bigskip\@afterindentfalse\@afterheading}%
                  {}%
              }%
          }%
      }%
  }
\makeatother
\AtBeginDocument{\strangeparsyntax}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}
The first line is never indented. The line continues on a new line, without an indent.
As you can see the second paragraph has an indent, so would have the following lines, but does not break into any whitespace.

Sometimes you do want to have whitespace. There won't be any indent again.
My question is: Is it possible to do this without extra new lines or par on the end of the line? And creating the whitespace just by the empty newline?


This paragraph will not be indented and the space before it will be doubled compared to the paragraph before this one.

\section{Section}
Leaving no space in between a sectioning command and the following text will give the normal spacing.

\section{Section}

With an additional new line between a heading and the text there will also be additional space.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I honestly like the effort you have put in this. While you don't recommend this, this was what I was asking for. I'll take in consideration this syntax should not be used, or face the consequences.

Comment: @Skinkie note that the used approach is similar to the way the LaTeX command `\obeylines` works (but that one only makes every newline a `\par` without the double newline means extra space bit).

Answer (score 1):

In basic TeX a blank line indicates the end of a paragraph. What you seem to be asking for with your desired syntax is that TeX will treat a blank line as starting a non-indented paragraph but then how are you going to indicate that your first lines of text are actually two paragraphs?

You mention novels. The `memoir` class (a superset of `book` and `report` classes) provides capabilities for what I called *Anonymous Breaks* consisting of either a number of blank lines followed by a non-indented paragraph or similar but with some decoration instead of blank lines.

```
% anonbreakprob.tex  SE 595254
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}
This is the input you want to use.
The first line is never indented. The line continues on a new line, 
without an indent.
As you can see the second paragraph has an indent, so would have the 
following lines, but does not break into any whitespace.

Sometimes you do want to have whitespace. There won't be any indent again.
My question is: Is it possible to do this without extra new lines or par 
on the end of the line? And creating the whitespace just by the empty newline?

\textbf{NO.}

\section{Section}

The first line is never indented. The line continues on a new line, 
without an indent.

As you can see the second paragraph has an indent, so would have the 
following lines, but does not break into any whitespace.

\plainbreak{1}

Sometimes you do want to have whitespace. There won't be any indent again.

My question is: Is it possible to do this without extra new lines or par 
on the end of the line? And creating the whitespace just by the empty newline?

\fancybreak{{*}\\{* * *}\\{*}}

Above I have used \verb!\plainbreak{1}! after the second paragraph and
just before this one I used \verb!\fancybreak{{*}\\{* * *}\\{*}}!.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, it is possible by turning the newline character active (see my second answer), but I'd not recommend using something like that throughout a document.

Comment: @Skillmon I think that you are saying not to use your `\strangepar` macro for a whole document. Forgive me if I'm mistaken. But I think that if one wants a "strange par" then that should be indicated in the appropriate place(s) in the code.

Comment: Yes, I'm saying that one shouldn't use it, but this also shows that it is (at least for this reduced MWE) possible to distinguish a line break and consecutive line breaks (but I haven't tested it inside of maths environments, lists, etc.). This `\strangeparsyntax` is close to how LaTeX's `\obeylines` works. Personally I'd use explicit markup for this in the form of a macro (either yours or something like in my other answer).

Comment: My first comment was just a comment on "how are you going to indicate that your first lines of text are actually two paragraphs?".

Answer (score 0):

TeX treats a new line as a space normally, and I'd advice you to keep it that way. Instead of using the syntax you're requesting, you could use some manual formatting for the few paragraphs that need this second formatting (usually in books those are few compared to the normal paragraphs.

You could use the following:

```
\documentclass[]{book}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}
The first line is never indented. The line continues on a new line, without an
indent.

As you can see the second paragraph has an indent, so would have the following
lines, but does not break into any whitespace.

\bigskip
\noindent
Sometimes you do want to have whitespace. There won't be any indent again.

My question is: Is it possible to do this without extra new lines or par on the
end of the line? And creating the whitespace just by the empty newline?
\end{document}
```

There can't be an empty line between `\noindent` and the following paragraph.

You could as well create a macro storing this formatting (this also uses two commands used by LaTeX, this way the next paragraph will not be indented and you could even use an empty line afterwards without issues.

```
\documentclass[]{book}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\parspace{\par\bigskip\@afterindentfalse\@afterheading}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}
The first line is never indented. The line continues on a new line, without an
indent.

As you can see the second paragraph has an indent, so would have the following
lines, but does not break into any whitespace.

\parspace

Sometimes you do want to have whitespace. There won't be any indent again.

My question is: Is it possible to do this without extra new lines or par on the
end of the line? And creating the whitespace just by the empty newline?
\end{document}
```

Output in both cases:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I don't see the benefit of changing the current "less than ideal" syntax to your proposals, since they only change the way how the space is created with a different syntax, it is still based on (a) command(s), not changing the behavior of Tex.

Comment: @Skinkie because changing the behaviour of TeX is a less than ideal solution. Anyway, I'll post a second answer.